# Запись данных в Excel-файл с помощью PHP. Как реализовать?

Tags: php, excel

Есть форма из 4-х полей (имя, телефон, E-mail, доп. информация), и
PHP-файл, отправляющий данные этих полей на почту (код ниже).

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
DEFINE('EMAIL_TO', 'info@info.info');

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: noreply@'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'' . "\r\n" .
              'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$message = "Имя: ".$_POST['name']."<br />";
if (!empty($_POST['email'])) $message .=  "Email: ".$_POST['email']."<br />";
if (!empty($_POST['phone'])) $message .=  "Телефон: ".$_POST['phone']."<br />";
if (!empty($_POST['info']))  $message .=  "Доп. информация: ".$_POST['info']."<br />";

switch ($_POST['form']) {
    case 'tyres':   
        mail(EMAIL_TO, 'Заявка (форма 1)', $message, $headers);
        break;
    case 'callback':
        mail(EMAIL_TO, 'Заявка (форма 2)', $message, $headers);
        break;
}
?>
```

Нужно реализовать запись трёх полей (имя, E-mail и телефон) в Excel-файл.
При каждой отправке заявки данные должны записываться в новой строке Excel-файла.

Можно ли как-то реализовать это? Информацию о записи в текстовый файл
нашёл, а вот как работать с экселевскими файлами, совершенно не понятно.

Никакого форматирования в Excel не нужно. Тупо запись по трём столбцам.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я так понимаю сложное форматирование не нужно, предлагаю:

сохранять данные в формате CSV, таким образом:

```
Ид;Имя;E-mail;Телефон
0;Катя;kate@microsoft.com;+79011234567
1;Billy;admin@microsoft.com;+79021234567
2;Иван Николаев;ivan@microsoft.com;+79031234567
```

Дать конечному файлу расширение .csv - оно отлично ладит с экселем и даже по умолчанию им и открывается. Если вам нужно только удобно сохранять информацию, уверен .xls не принципиально для вас и формат CSV справится с вашей задачей более чем.

Короче вот рабочий вариант, вставьте свои переменные и всё, он будет дописывать новые записи в начало файла, ошибки закомментированы '@' для первого запуска, когда файла ещё нет. Можете убрать '@', по желанию :)

```
<?php

$name = 'Иванов Иван';
$email = 'ivan@yandex.ru';
$phone = '+7(903)123 20 56';
$today = date("F j, Y, g:i a");

$file = 'sample.csv';
$tofile = "'$name';'$email';'$phone';'$today'\n";
$bom = "\xEF\xBB\xBF";
@file_put_contents($file, $bom . $tofile . file_get_contents($file));

?>
```

Comment: Мне пришлось так и делать потому как PHPExcel очень много памяти требует  там 6 тысяч строк и 512 мб памяти надо.

Comment: Олег, скажите пожалуйста, как записывать в данный файл (CSV)? Или просто записывать строку в описанном вами формате 2;Иван Николаев;ivan@microsoft.com;+79031234567? И автоматом столбцы создаются?

Comment: Олег. Я почитал про CSV. Скорее всего это то, что нужно. Спасибо. Сейчас попробую.

Comment: Как вам угодно, если можете "в ручную", но лучше с помощью fputcsv();
информация и примеры: http://www.php.su/functions/?fputcsv
ах да и если настроить fopen с атрибутом "a" то он будет новые строчки дописывать в конец файла а не переписывать полностью. уверен к вашей форме обратной связи это более подойдёт

Comment: Да. Нужно дописывать строки, а не переписывать. А может есть такой волшебный способ, когда строка вписывается перед первой, а не после последней? Т.е. новые записи сверху.

Comment: Можно, если в ручную будете писать (без putcsv):

<?php
$file = 'sample.csv';
$add = "1;Ivan;ivan@microsoft.com;+79011234567" . "\n";
file_put_contents($file,$add . file_get_contents($file));
?>

пожалуйста проверяйте тк пишу "в слепую".

Comment: А в чём разница вручную, и не вручную? Как правильнее?
И ещё, почему-то вручную когда, то запись встаёт не в строке
над прошлой, а в одной и той же строке.

Comment: http://pastebin.ru/NZgrCOgy 

Проверил работает + решена проблема с кодировкой. Просто вставьте свои переменные.

Answer (score 4):

Есть масса классов и библиотек. Одна из них, которую я когда-то использовал, была [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/). Все замечательно описано и гибко работает.

[Здесь](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/tree/develop/Examples) масса готовых примеров.
А [в этом примере](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Examples/10autofilter-selection-1.php) с самого начала показано, как заносить данные в `WorkSheet`. В других примерах тоже есть аналогичное.

Comment: Пожалуйста. Можно. С помощью `setCellValue(cell,value)`.

Comment: Вот, из моих закладок - http://blog.kron0s.com/phpexcel, http://blog.kron0s.com/reuse-excel-business-logic-with-phpexcel и далее по ссылкам.
Есть вот еще видео - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7xGCK8Y885s и описание пошаговое с примерами http://webformyself.com/generaciya-prajs-lista-v-formate-excel-pri-pomoshhi-php/

Comment: Вы сказали, что можно в существующий файл вписывать новые строки с помощью setCellValue(cell,value). А как открыть тот самый файл,в который нужно вписать новую строку (допустим, он на сервере лежит)? И также как потом сохранить результат? А то только понятно, как генерировать файл с нуля и сразу же скачивать. А как работать с существующим и сохранять в нём изменения, не понятно.

Comment: По идее, как-то нужно узнать, сколько всего строк в файле, чтобы записать данные в следующую.

Comment: Мне не нужно генерировать файлы. Нужно взять уже подготовленный файл с четырьмя столбцами (имя, имэйл, телефон и доп. информация), и после последней строки вписать новую строку. Так может быть можно обойтись без PHPExcel?

Comment: Я сейчас не около компьютера (пишу с мобильного телефона). Библиотека позволяет работать с уже существующим файлами. Широкий диапазон методов типа getXXX позволяет получать всю информацию о текущем файле. Ну и, само собой, вносить изменения и записывать результат. Я думаю, на многочисленных форумах вы найдете рабочие примеры по теме. Я сейчас, увы, на память не помню имена методов и их сигнатуры.

Comment: Я вполне уверен, что вы правы. Но реально уже всё перерыл. Никак не могу найти то, что мне нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Как возможную реализацию данной задачи могу предложить следующее: при каждой отправке формы пишите данные в базу и заново создавайте excel-файл. Для генерации excel-файла могу посоветовать библиотеку PHPExcel.

Пример как с ней работать можно посмотреть [здесь](http://web-arxitector.ru/index.php?page=articles-php-PHPExcel). Правда в данном примере созданный excel-файл не сохраняется на диск а отдается на скачивание в браузер, для того чтобы файл сохранить на диск вам нужно будет строчку

`$objWriter->save('php://output');`

заменить на

`$objWriter->save("название_файла.xlsx");`

и убрать заголовки.

Но не могу сказать, как поведет себя данная реализация при большом количестве пользователей, если ожидается большое количество одновременных запросов нужно подумать о целесообразности такого метода.